# Open wrt asterisk 15 huawei e171 входящие не работают помогите

Tags: asterisk, sip, openwrt

Asterisk 15
huawei 171 исходящие работают. При входящем ошибка

при исходящем звонке в логе:

```
channel.c:215 channel_request: [dongle0] Request to call on device which can not make call at this moment
[Nov  6 10:09:06] WARNING[3396][C-0000000b]: app_dial.c:2510 dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'Dongle' (cause 44 - Requested channel not available)


dongle show devices
ID           Group State      RSSI Mode Submode Provider Name  Model      Firmware          IMEI             IMSI             Number
dongle0      0     GSM not re 23   5    4       MegaFon RUS    E173       11.126.85.00.209  35************  2501********  +7996********


OpenWrt*CLI> dongle show device settings dongle0
------------- Settings ------------
  Device                  : dongle0
  Audio                   : /dev/ttyUSB1
  Data                    : /dev/ttyUSB2
  IMEI                    : 35466***************
  IMSI                    : 2501****************
  Channel Language        : en
  Context                 : default
  Exten                   :
  Group                   : 0
  RX gain                 : 3
  TX gain                 : 3
  U2Diag                  : -1
  Use CallingPres         : Yes
  Default CallingPres     : Presentation Allowed, Passed Screen
  Auto delete SMS         : No
  Disable SMS             : No
  Reset Dongle            : Yes
  SMS PDU                 : No
  Call Waiting            : auto
  DTMF                    : relax
  Minimal DTMF Gap        : 45
  Minimal DTMF Duration   : 80
  Minimal DTMF Interval   : 200
  Initial device state    : start


sip.conf
[general]
allowguest=yes
context=public
localnet=192.168.0.1/255.255.0.0

[111]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=111
context=default
canreinvite=yes
dtmfmode=rfc2833
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
qualify=yes


extensions.conf

; directory location of this file: /etc/asterisk

[globals]

[general]
static=yes
writeprotect=yes
autofallthrough=yes

[default]
exten => 111, 1, Dial(SIP/111)
exten => 222, 1, Dial(SIP/222)
exten => 333, 1, Dial(SIP/333)
exten => 444, 1, Dial(SIP/444)

exten => _7X.,1,Dial(Dongle/dongle0/holdother:+${FILTER(0-9,${EXTEN})})
exten => _+7X.,1,Dial(Dongle/dongle0/holdother:+${FILTER(0-9,${EXTEN})})
exten => _8X.,1,Dial(Dongle/dongle0/holdother:+7${FILTER(0-9,${EXTEN:1})})
exten => _007X.,1,Dial(Dongle/dongle0/holdother:+7${FILTER(0-9,${EXTEN:3})})
exten => h,1,Hangup()

[dongle-incoming-sms]
exten => sms,1,Noop(Incoming SMS from ${CALLERID(num)} ${BASE64_DECODE(${SMS_BASE64})})
exten => sms,n,System(echo '${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)} ... ${DONGLENAME} ... ${CALLERID(num)}: ${BASE64_DECODE(${SMS_BASE64})}' >> /var/log/asterisk/sms.t
exten => sms,n,Hangup()

[dongle-incoming-ussd]
exten => ussd,1,Noop(Incoming USSD: ${BASE64_DECODE(${USSD_BASE64})})
exten => ussd,n,System(echo '${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)} ... ${DONGLENAME}: ${BASE64_DECODE(${USSD_BASE64})}' >> /var/log/asterisk/ussd.txt)
exten => ussd,n,Hangup()

[dongle-incoming]
include => dongle-incoming-sms
include => dongle-incoming-ussd

exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/111)
exten => h,1,Hangup()
```

Comment: Увы, за сутки не нашлось ни одного телепата, который бы смог прозреть суть возникающей при входящем ошибки.

Comment: Кто то сказал что надо Nat на входящие настроить в экстенш. Как это сделать?